# How to authorize other email adress for google play store?

Tags: google-play-store, authorization

I can install apps on our family tablet using my personal Google account. Somehow I've set this up in the past, so I have all my devices under one Google account. Note that the tablet is officially registered on an other Google account.

I want to do this again for the tablet of my grandmother, but I don't know how anymore how I've done this in the past.

I have my grandmother's tablet here. How can I authorize myself to install apps on her tablet using my own Google account?

Thx in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must first add your google account to the tablet. The Google Play app won't let you switch an account until there are two or more accounts on the device.

So first add your google account. You will probably want to disable all of the synchronizing options.

Once that is done, open the Google Play app, and you'll see the option to switch accounts. On top of that, you will be able to "Push Install" apps to the tablet from your desktop computer (provided you're logged into the same google account).

The downside, of course, is that there is now a device that can synchronize your contacts, gmail, photos, etc that you don't control. Your grandma could decide to purchase in-app items or purchase new apps (though you can require a password for that, at least).

Alternatively, if you only want to install a few of the paid apps you own, you can temporarily add your account, install the apps, then remove the account. The apps remain installed, even without the linked account.

Comment: This pretty much answers every question I could think of. Thx a lot Stephen!

Comment: Well what the *.. This even answers this question: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/65907/why-are-preinstalled-apps-not-registered-in-play-store-on-new-devices

Now I've configured my own account temporarily on the new device, all preinstalled apps are suddenly registered to play store and updating! Why does Google don't do this on newly created Google account??