# Why are preinstalled apps not registered in play store on new devices?

Tags: google-play-store

This is the 2nd time I noticed this. Once with a new Samsung galaxy s3 (with newly created Google account) and now with a new Samsung Galaxy Note (also with a newly created Google account).

I've just registered 2 new Samsung Galaxy Note tablets. One with my personal, existing Google account. And one for a friend with a new Google account I just created.

On my personal tablet, all installed apps where registered in the play store and they all said "update".

On my friends tablet with the new Google account, there are **NONE** apps installed on the device, according to Google play. What this means is that I need to find each and every one of the installed apps in the play store **manually** and update them. Or else I wouldn't receive update notifications from those apps.

This is very annoying. Especially with the loads of bloatware preïnstalled on new android devices these days.

Is there any known fix for this issue? How can I have Google Play store register all apps installed on device and show them in the **my apps section**?

Thx in advance!

Comment: Well what the *.. Now I've configured my own account temporarily on the new device according to [this answer](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/65906/how-to-authorize-other-email-adress-for-google-play-store), all preinstalled apps are suddenly registered to play store and updating! Why does Google don't do this on newly created Google account??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because Google can back up which apps you have installed on your Google account, and restore them when you associate your account with a new device. Since your friend's account is new, the apps have not been installed yet, and are therefore not shown.

As for why the apps are not shown as installed, it's because they're not installed from Google play, but from Samsung. If I remember correctly, Samsung has it's own Samsung Apps app, which handles updates for preinstalled applications unless they're associated with their Google Play counterparts.